# how to save dataframe into csv pyspark

Tags: csv, dataframe, hdfs, pyspark

I am trying to save dataframe into hdfs system.
It gets saved as part-0000 and into multiple parts.
I want to save it as an excel sheet or just one part file?
How can we achieve this?

code used so far:

```
  df1.write.csv('/user/gtree/tree.csv')
```

Comment: As one csv file? Or as one excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataframe is being saved based on its partitions(multiple partitions= multiple files). You can coalesce or bring your partitions down to 1, so that only 1 file can be written.

Link:https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce

```
df1.coalesce(1).write.csv('/user/gtree/tree.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.repartition(1)` to set the partitions to only 1

```
df.repartition(1).save(filePath)
```