# How to save pyspark data frame in a single csv file

Tags: pyspark

This is in continuation of this [how to save dataframe into csv pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60498321/how-to-save-dataframe-into-csv-pyspark) thread.

I'm trying to save my pyspark data frame df in my pyspark 3.0.1. So I wrote

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv('mypath/df.csv)
```

But after executing this, I'm seeing a folder named df.csv in mypath which contains 4 following files

```
1._committed_..
2._started_...
3._Success  
4. part-00000-.. .csv
```

Can you suggest to me how do I save all data in `df.csv`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.coalesce(1)` to save the file in just 1 csv partition, then rename this csv and move it to the desired folder.

Here is a function that does that:

`df`: Your df
`fileName`: Name you want to for the csv file
`filePath`: Folder where you want to save to

```
def export_csv(df, fileName, filePath):
  
  filePathDestTemp = filePath + ".dir/" 

  df\
    .coalesce(1)\
    .write\
    .csv(filePathDestTemp) # use .csv to save as csv

  listFiles = dbutils.fs.ls(filePathDestTemp)
  for subFiles in listFiles:
    if subFiles.name[-4:] == ".csv":
      
      dbutils.fs.cp (filePathDestTemp + subFiles.name,  filePath + fileName+ '.csv')

  dbutils.fs.rm(filePathDestTemp, recurse=True)
```

Comment: Hi I am trying this as it looks like one of the simpler solutions, however I am struggling to get the library imported: I ran `!pip3 install dbutils` but then when I run your first line: `listFiles = dbutils.fs.ls(path_nm+'.dir/')` I get the error `AttributeError: module 'dbutils' has no attribute 'fs' ` . I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: dbutils is a feature from Databricks. If you are not running this on Databricks, you would need to rewrite it to fit your stack.

Comment: Thnx - I got a collegue to help me with this one as we are running on Cloudera.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get one file named `df.csv` as output, you can first write into a temporary folder, then move the part file generated by Spark and rename it.

These steps can be done using [Hadoop FileSystem API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) available via JVM gateway :

```
temp_path = "mypath/__temp"
target_path = "mypath/df.csv"

df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv(temp_path)

Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

# get the part file generated by spark write
fs = Path(temp_path).getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
csv_part_file = fs.globStatus(Path(temp_path + "/part*"))[0].getPath()

# move and rename the file
fs.rename(csv_part_file, Path(target_path))
fs.delete(Path(temp_path), True)
```

Comment: it works like magic. thanks for sharing. I have one comment - do you happen to know how to preserve the headers? coalesce does not have the 'option' so looking for you help?

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` when the path is `None`, the function returns the csv as a string. You can write this string directly to any file on the dbfs with `dbutils.fs.put`.

```
csv_buffer = df.toPandas().to_csv(sep=';', header=True, index=False)
dbutils.fs.put('mypath/df.csv', csv_buffer, overwrite=True)
```

I guess this only works if all data fits into the driver node's memory.